# how to check certain numbers in python list using range function

Tags: python, list

I have a list of intergers

```
J=[10,11,12,24,2,8,9,]
```

how can write a program to print yes if 10,11 are in List J without considering their current index position

> eg(J[0] and J[1] respectively,ie they could be anywhere in a list

Comment: if (10 in J) and (11 in J): print("yes")

Comment: @Jean & Serjik  thanks,is suppose i start with empty list,and add numbers in a list(ie i dont numbers in advance),will it be the same as your answers

Comment: @Jean & Serjik  thanks,is suppose i start with empty list,and add numbers in a list(ie i dont numbers in advance),will it be the same as your answers

Comment: see my edit. of course it works.

Answer (score 2):

simplest way (without using `range`)

```
J=[11,12,24,2,8,9,]
# add a value to the end of the list
J.append(10)
# test
print(10 in J and 11 in J)
```

for bigger lists you'll see that the performance is not that good: `O(len(J))`

Since you don't care about the order/indexes, you can use the exact same syntax, only if you pass `J` as a `set`

```
J={11,12,24,2,8,9,}  # or J=set([11,12,24,2,8,9,])
J.add(10)  # add a value
print(10 in J and 11 in J)
```

make `J` a million items, looking for items at the "end" of the list is amazingly faster using a `set` than using a `list`

limitations:

- order not guaranteed/preserved
- duplicate items discarded